# How to install repmgr 4.2 (ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

`apt-get install postgresql-10-repmgr`  give me repmgr 4.3.  However, my primary server is still on 4.2.

How do I install repmgr version 4.2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Disto? What repo is this from?

Comment: curl https://dl.2ndquadrant.com/default/release/get/deb | sudo bash

Answer (score -1):

An archive of old packages (3.3.2 and later) for Debian/Ubuntu-based systems is available here:
http://atalia.postgresql.org/morgue/r/repmgr/